# Git delete a file with space in name

Tags: git

I have added a file and also committed `webpageone fresh.rhtml`. I left a space in the name. When I a try to remove it, using:

```
git rm -f /webpageone fresh.rhtml
```

I get this error:

```
pathspec '/webpageone' did not match any files.
```

I tried removing another file and it worked... So the problem is the spacing. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a shell problem, not a git problem. You need to escape the space. This should work:

```
git rm -f /webpageone\ fresh.rhtml
```

I guess this should also work:

```
git rm -f "/webpageone fresh.rhtml"
```

Comment: I used second command mentioned here but it did not work. It worked after i removed slash in second command.                                                                                                                                git rm -f "New Text Document.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this thread after nearly 12 years, the way that it works now is:

`git rm -r 'File name'/Folder/*.*`

using apostrophes for the file name with spaces.